# Persistent Selection Multiselect Listbox Entries

Tags: jquery, html, django, django-templates, listbox-control

I have an html form. After submittal I need to have the selected item(s) for each form control remain selected. This works for radio buttons, checkboxes, drop-down lists, but not for my multiselect listbox. I also need this ability so I can pass the form data to a jquery function to perform other tasks. The process works on other pages without multiselect listboxes. I am using Django server-side and normally do a 'for loop' or 'if statement' to check user selections. I can get the selection as a list from my javascript, but in the Chrome network panel, it gives the list items as separate form variables. What is the method to get this formatting?

**Update**
The jfiddle provided by meni181818 should work and I think it is the correct direction. However, I have updated my page to only include this code and it doesn't work. I can copy the code into a jfiddle and have it work, but not on my page. I'm not sure if it's a Django issue. The only additional code on the page is:

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I have tried a few permutations, but my list of selected options is always one post behind the currently selected options. I currently have the list as a hidden input with value equal to the result of the set script provided in meni181818's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all the selected items as array:

```
arrVal = $("select").val();
```

and to JSON:

```
JSON.stringify(arrVal);
```

if you want you can return it as JSON, and parse it to array with js\jq:

```
var arrJson = JSON.parse(THE_JSON_STRING);
```

and set the selected items:

```
$("select").val(arrJson);
```

**get & set demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZA82M/2/**

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for my case. I have to create the list options in a loop, which I think may be part of the problem.

Comment: After further testing, the exact code in the jfiddle does not work in my html code. I have everything within the <body> tag.

Answer (score 0):

The method provided by meni181818 works for me. I had to change some things around because of my specific needs. I used hidden inputs instead of a

tag, which meant changing .text() to .val(). I needed to do this so I could pass the values through my Django backend and keep them after posting the form.